# Cannot center card component (element) when using Element

Tags: css

**1. Use technology (product)**

HTML5,Vue,[Element](https://element.eleme.cn/#/en-US/component/installation)

**2. Problem description**

[image: Picture]As shown, the main card cannot be centered

**3. Expected results (problems expected to be solved)**

Make `<div id="app"><el-card class="box-card" style="width:480px;margin:auto;">` vertical center

**4. Reference materials**

[Element related documents](https://element.eleme.cn/#/en-US/component/card)

**5. Solutions that have been tried (failed)**

（1）

```
#app{
display:flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
}
```

（2）

```
#app{
position:relative;
.box-card{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right:0;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: auto;
    }
}
```

**6. Code (front-end HTML)**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <title>Login - Unified authentication for Lime Network users</title>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.staticfile.org/element-ui/2.13.2/index.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.staticfile.org/element-ui/2.13.2/locale/en.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.staticfile.org/element-ui/2.13.2/theme-chalk/index.css">
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <div id="app">
            <el-card class="box-card" style="width:480px;margin:auto;">
                <p style="text-align:center">Login - Unified authentication for Lime Network users</p>
                <el-form ref="form" :model="form" status-icon :rules="rules" label-position="left" label-width="auto">
                    <el-form-item label="Username" prop="username">
                        <el-input v-model="form.username" prefix-icon="el-icon-user"></el-input>
                    </el-form-item>
                    <el-form-item label="Password" prop="password">
                        <el-input v-model="form.password" prefix-icon="el-icon-lock" show-password></el-input>
                    </el-form-item>
                    <el-form-item label="Remember me">
                        <el-switch v-model="form.remember"></el-switch>
                    </el-form-item>
                    <el-form-item label="Other ways">
                        <el-button type="text" @click="oauth_github()">GitHub</el-button>
                        <el-button type="text" @click="oauth_gitee()">Gitee</el-button>
                    </el-form-item>
                    <el-form-item>
                        <el-button type="primary" @click="submitForm('form')">Login</el-button>
                        <el-button @click="resetForm('form')">Reset</el-button>
                    </el-form-item>
                </el-form>
            </el-card>
        </div>
        <script>
        Script part omitted
        </script>
    </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem has been solved

```
body {
        margin: 0px;
    }
    #app {
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100vh;
        display:flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
    }
```